# RUBY: Using An Array of Structs

Tags: arrays, ruby, struct, reference

Here is my code. When I write to one variable all the elements change.
(It is a bowling program)

```
Frame = Struct.new(:first, :second, :total)
frame = Frame.new(1,2,3)
frames = Array.new(11,frame)
print "frames[0].first: " + frames[0].first.to_s + newLine
print "frames[1].first: " + frames[1].first.to_s + newLine
game[0].first = 10
print "frames[0].first: " + frames[0].first.to_s + newLine
print "frames[1].first: " + frames[1].first.to_s + newLine
frames[1].first = 20
print "frames[0].first: " + frames[0].first.to_s + newLine
print "frames[1].first: " + frames[1].first.to_s + newLine
```

print out:

```
frames[0].first: 1
frames[1].first: 1
frames[0].first: 10
frames[1].first: 10
frames[0].first: 20
frames[1].first: 20
```

Answer (score 2):

As Sergio Tulentsev already wrote, the behavior you observe happens because you reference the exact same `Frame` into all array slots.

Instead you can create new and different frames for each array slots by using [`Array.new` with a block](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Array.html#method-c-new):

```
Frame = Struct.new(:first, :second, :total)
frames = Array.new(11) { Frame.new(1, 2, 3) }
```

Btw when you change from `print` to `puts` then newlines will be added automatically to the end of the output. And when you use string interpolation instead of string concatenation then there is no need to call `to_s` explicitly because string interpolation calls `to_s` implicit.

```
puts "frames[0].first: #{frames[0].first}"
puts "frames[1].first: #{frames[1].first}"
game[0].first = 10
puts "frames[0].first: #{frames[0].first}"
puts "frames[1].first: #{frames[1].first}"
frames[1].first = 20
puts "frames[0].first: #{frames[0].first}"
puts "frames[1].first: #{frames[1].first}"
```

Answer (score 1):

> all the elements change

array's elements are all references to the same underlying Frame object. When you use one of the references to mutate the object, the changes are observable through the other references.

Comment: I knew what was happening. I just couldn’t find out what the correct code for this was. Thank you Spickermann for giving it to me. Does anyone know a good resource that has this?